# F4Player experiencing problems with Live Stream

Tags: flash, stream, live-streaming

I installed F4Player for playing an HTTP MP4 Livestream. I set the video URL and when playing the same URL with VLC all is working. When I click on play in f4player, the stream gets loaded (displays in network mobitor) but in the console logs appears this:

```
initializating ...
Stream URL: null
Thumbnail: thumbnail.jpg
NetStatusEvent: NetConnection.Connect.Success
NetConnection connected to null
Play file: http://my-server.com:3000/T-8468-3329-3.ts
Video dimensions: 480x270
NetConnection is: true
Autoplay: http://my-server.com:3000/T-8468-3329-3.ts
NetStatusEvent: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

The source code looks like this:

```
<div id="player">
         <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="player.swf?v1.3.5" width="480" id="f" name="f" height="270" flashvars="skin=skins/mySkin.swf&thumbnail=thumbnail.jpg&video=http://my-server.com:3000/T-8468-3329-3.ts&live=1" allowScriptAccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#000000"/>
                        <noembed>
                            You need Adobe Flash Player to watch this video. <br>
                            <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Download it from Adobe.</a>
                            <a href="http://gokercebeci.com/dev/f4player" title="flv player">flv player</a>
                        </noembed>
  </div>
```

What have I missconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

What is your streaming server? lets consider RTMP. The best way you can do it is :

`<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="player.swf" width="480" id="f1" name="f1" height="270" flashvars="skin=skins/mySkin.swf&stream=rtmp://yourserverip/Streamings&streamname=my_stream_id&live=1&thumbnail=thumbnail.jpg" allowScriptAccess="true" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#000000"/>`

I think you should change your code to something like this. And dont use port once.

Comment: My Server sends a HTTP Stream